# Is it possible to use scanf("%d" &i) and use the first number inputted only, and nothing else?

Tags: c

First off, I am not familiar with c at all. It would be great if you treated me like a total beginner, which I am.

So, the problem I have is that I don't seem to be able to make it so that the program only takes the information of one number, uses it, then disregards any other information.

At the moment I have something similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int i, ret;
    char c, type;
    do
    {
        printf("Convert ASCII # to character\n");
        printf("q: Quit.\n");
        scanf("%c", &type);
/* I use the " if(type== 'n'); " a number of times. */
/* I left the others out to  simplify what my problem is. */
         if(type=='1'){
             printf("ASCII NUMBER -> CHAR \n");
             printf("\t Please input one ASCII code \n"); 
             int ret = scanf("%d", &i);
/* My aim here is to get the amount of integers the user inputs,*/ 
/* and use that to categorize, but I think I am failing to do so. */
             if(ret==1){
                 printf("\t The character for ASCII code %d is -> '%c' \n\n", i, i);
                 break;
             }
             else{
                 printf("Please input one number./n/n");
                 break;
             }
         }

    }
    while(type=='q');   
    return 0;
/* A problem I face a lot is where the program would terminate*/ 
/* even when the while conditions weren't met. */
}
```

I hope you could understand what I'm trying to do by looking at the code above.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

the program ends because of the character [enter] left in the input buffer.
You give input value for type then for i and press [enter]. this [enter] is a character left in the input buffer which will be read by next

```
scanf("%c",type);
```

so the loop exits. Therefore use `getchar()` after

```
int ret = scanf("%d", &i);
```

To clear the input buffer. and the loop will not end unexpectedly.
Make these changes,

```
 printf("\t Please input one ASCII code \n"); 
             int ret = scanf("%d", &i);
             getchar();          //this will read the [enter] character in input buffer
/* My aim here is to get the amount of integers the user inputs,*/ 
/* and use that to categorize, but I think I am failing to do so. */
             if(ret==1){
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not too familiar with using getchar(). What would I do to keep the loop and not have the enter key left in the input buffer?

Comment: @user3536816 after you read the integer using scanf() `\n` will be left in input buffer. so just add one `getchar()` statement and try to execute program.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I find it better to use `fgets()` (alternatively, if you are using C99, `gets_s()` -- although I still prefer fgets() for maximum portability to older compiler environments) for all user-based input, then if necessary use `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, and the like to convert the string into other data types, as this will read data by line in a way that is buffer-safe and you won't have to worry about things left in the input buffer.  This is especially true for user-based input which is never well-formed (due to typos, etc).  `scanf()` really only works well when reading from well-formed input files.

See the comp.lang.c FAQ which describes some of the problems that often occur when using `scanf()` in detail, including the problem you are seeing above, where inputs seem to be getting skipped:

- http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html
- http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html
- http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html
- http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfjam.html

To find out more about any C standard library function, at a linux command prompt (or Google) type: `man 3 fgets` and so on.

- fgets: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets
- sscanf: http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf
- strtol: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol

Example:

```
char buffer[256], type;
fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin );
if( sscanf( buffer, "%c", &type ) == 1 ) {
    // Was able to read a char from the buffer, now you can use it.
}
else {
    // Wasn't able to read a char from the buffer.  handle it if required.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! However, I have no idea what sscanf() and strtol() does. I guess I have a long way to go :s.

Comment: Added example and 'howto' for finding documentation in C standard APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations and the links for the other guides. I'll be sure to take a look at them.